lightning datatable displaying only first two rows and ignoring others
I have a custom LWC component where I'm displaying data from my object and implementing pagination.
I'm retrieving all the data from Apex and can see the data returned from Apex.
To display the data in the LWC, I'm using the lightning-datatable component.
However, this LWC component is only displaying the first two rows and is ignoring the other rows. I'm not sure what's happening here.
HTML:
    <!--RECORDS PER PAGE-->
    <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="slds-list_inline slds-p-bottom_xx-small slds-m-left_small">
            <label class="slds-text-color_weak slds-p-horizontal_x-small slds-m-top_x-small" for="recordsPerPage">Page Size:</label>
            <div class="slds-select_container ">
                <select class="slds-select" id="recordsPerPage" onchange={handleRecordsPerPage}>
                    <template for:each={pageSizeOptions} for:item="option">
                        <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                    </template>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-top_small ">
        <lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
                             data={recordsToDisplay}
                             hide-checkbox-column="true"    
                             columns={columns}
                             onrowaction={handleRowAction}
        >
        </lightning-datatable>
        
    </div>
     <!--PAGE NAVIGATION-->
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">
        <lightning-button disabled={bDisableFirst} icon-name="utility:jump_to_left" label="First" class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small" alternative-text="first page" onclick={firstPage}></lightning-button>

        <lightning-button disabled={bDisableFirst} icon-name="utility:chevronleft" label="Previous" alternative-text="Previous" onclick={previousPage}></lightning-button>
        &nbsp;
        <span class="slds-badge">Showing {pageNumber} &nbsp;of&nbsp; {totalPages} &nbsp;&nbsp;Page(s)</span>
        &nbsp;
        <lightning-button disabled={bDisableLast} icon-name="utility:chevronright" label="Next" alternative-text="Next" onclick={nextPage} class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>

        <lightning-button disabled={bDisableLast} icon-name="utility:jump_to_right" label="Last" alternative-text="last page" onclick={lastPage} icon-position="right"></lightning-button>
    </div>

</template>

JS:
connectedCallback() {
        this.columns = [{
            label: 'Group Name',
            fieldName: 'Name'
        },
        {
            label: 'Member Group',
            fieldName: 'Group_Members__c'
        },
        {
            label: 'Comments',
            fieldName: 'Comments__c'
        },
        { type: "button", initialWidth: 210, typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Delete',
            name: 'Delete',
            title: 'Delete',
            disabled: false,
            value: 'delete',
            iconPosition: 'left',
            iconName:'utility:delete',
            variant:'destructive'
        }
        },
    ];

    //get records from the Apex 
    getCorporateGroupList()
        .then((result) => {
            if(result != null){
                console.log('>>> inside corporate group list... ');
                console.table(result);
                this.record = result; 
                this.totalRecords = result.length; //update total Records Count
                if(result.length < 5){
                    this.pageSize = 1;
                }else{
                    this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0]; //set page size with default value as first option 
                }               
                this.paginationHelper(); //helper method to update pagination object 
            }

            
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log('error while fetching records -->' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }    


paginationHelper(){

        console.log('>>> totalRecords... '+this.totalRecords);
        console.log('>>> pageSize... '+this.pageSize);

        this.recordsToDisplay = []; 
        // calculate total Pages
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageSize);
        console.log('>>> totalPages... '+this.totalPages);

        if (this.pageNumber <= 1){
            this.pageNumber = 1; 
        } else if(this.pageNumber >= this.totalPages){
            this.pageNumber = this.totalPages; 
        }
        console.log('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'+ this.totalRecords);
        //set records to display on current page
        for(let i = (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.pageSize; i < this.pageNumber * this.pageSize; i++){
            console.log('this.totalRecords>>>'+this.totalRecords)
            if(i === this.totalRecords){
                break;
            }
            this.recordsToDisplay.push(this.record[i]);
        }
        console.log('>>> records to display... '+JSON.stringify(this.recordsToDisplay));
        //console.table(this.recordsToDisplay);
    }

handleRecordsPerPage(events){
        this.pageSize = events.target.value; 
        this.paginationHelper();  
    }

    previousPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber - 1; 
        this.paginationHelper();      
    }

    nextPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1; 
        this.paginationHelper();   
    }

    firstPage(){
        this.pageNumber = 1; 
        this.paginationHelper(); 
    }

    lastPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.totalPages; 
        this.paginationHelper();   
    }

    handleRowAction(event){
        const recId = event.detail.row.Id;
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        deleteRecord(recId)
        .then(() =>{
            window.location.reload();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log("error, " + error);
        });
    }

Please note the log at >>> records to display... is displaying correct records which should get displayed it's only in ui I'm seeing the first two rows.
